# wifi suddenly stopped working in ubuntu 14.04 lts,drivers are installed but i think i messed with configuration

Tags: networking, wireless

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12723155/

here is the link with every result and problem i am facing with my wifi

Answer (score 0):

First, I see this in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg
off speed 100
exit 0
```

It should be amended to:

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100
exit 0
```

Second, since Network Manager is installed and running, I suggest you eliminate all settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` except:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Restart the computer and see if the wireless has returned. If needed, I will edit this answer to add troubleshooting steps.